# Style div content on a right from image

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to make in same div image and description but I want to make a description left of an image. When I add image, all description goes down. How can I make description container be on the right side from image without going under the image?

CSS / HTML

```css
#thirdContainer {
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-image: url();
    background-size: cover;
     }
    #aboutUs {
        padding-top: 15vh;
        color: black;
        font-family: 'Martel', serif;
        max-width: inherit;
        text-align: left;
        padding-left: 100vh;
    }
    #aboutUsContent{
    padding-left: 50em;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-right: 35em;
    }
    #breadImage {
    padding-top: 20vh;
    margin-left: 8vh;
    }
```

```html
<div id="thirdContainer">
<img id="breadImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100.jpg/09f/fff">
<h2 id="aboutUs"><strong>About Us</strong></h2>
<div id="aboutUsContent">
<p>Description content</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many options out there.

**A quick solution using flex:**
*(Added one more div to wrap the description fields together)*

```css
.flex-grid {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="thirdContainer" class="flex-grid">
<img id="breadImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100.jpg/09f/fff">
<div>
<h2 id="aboutUs"><strong>About Us</strong></h2>
<div id="aboutUsContent">
<p>Description content</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```